# using VC debug heap under pinvoke

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I am using a third-party C library via Pinvoke from c#. There are lots of returned blocks which I have to delete and I am worried that some code paths might have missed some free calls.

If this was a pure c/c++ app I would use _CrtSetDbgFlag etc. to make sure; is there some way I can use the heap debug functions in this situation?

I guess the better question is - what techniques can I use to check for leaks in this situation?

Comment: No.  Write tests, use umhd.exe

Comment: umhd wont get overwhelmed by the CLR heap activity?

Comment: Never tried it, you'll find out.  The CLR uses VirtualAlloc, not HeapAlloc.